# BuildError while using routing with variables

Tags: web-applications, flask, flask-wtforms, web-frameworks, flask-restful

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/about/<name>')
def about(name):
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I go to: http://localhost:5000/about/abc

This code gives me:

**BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'about'. Did you forget to specify values ['name']?**

What am I doing wrong ?

The solution was to add **name=name** in layout.html which about.html inherits. I don't understand whats happening here.

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('about', name=name) }}">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you failed to create an about.html in your templates folder. Make sure the folder is called templates and it is in the same directory as your python code.